# Different output for DateTime.strftime vs Time.strftime for timezone abbreviations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, time, format

I feel like I am missing something very simple here.  I read the [APIDock](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime) am expecting `%Z` to return an abbreviated timezone (e.g., `PST`).  It does this for a `Time` object but not a `DateTime`.

What am I missing?

```
irb(main):008:0> Time.now.strftime("%Z")
=> "PST"
irb(main):009:0> DateTime.now.strftime("%Z")
=> "-08:00"
```

`ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin15]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation on [`DateTime#strftime`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime) a bit unclear:

> `%Z` — Time zone abbreviation name or something similar information.

To make it possible to show the offset both ways, `DateTime` shows the numeric value. To retrieve the abbreviated name, one should explicitly cast `DateTime` object to `Time`:

```
▶ DateTime.now.to_time.strftime("%Z")
#⇒ "CET"
```

Comment: Thanks - I am not sure if this is a documentation issue, or a functionality issue.  I opened a ticket: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/13231

Comment: Honestly: I am pretty sure it’s done on purpose, _to make it possible to show the offset both ways_ without adding an additional `%`-mapper.

Answer (score 1):

There are few things -

`DateTime.now`

gives you an object of DateTime class. Also I have gone through [DateTime class Doc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime) and checked %Z in terminal, It doesn't work.

And As mudasobwa said, by using `to_time` method you are converting DateTime object to Time class object.

So `DateTime.now.to_time` and `Time.now` both gives you the same thing.

Conclusion - I will suggest you to use

> Time.now.strftime("%Z")

instead of

> DateTime.now.to_time.strftime("%Z")